# How to suppress view button Push Notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

In the apple documentation, they show a notification where there's no view button, just an "OK" button.

How could I do this in my app.

does this have to be implemented in the payload code, or in the local app?

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, I found it has to do with the "body" element of the message:

Here's an example

```
{"aps":
     {"alert":{"body":"You got a new message!",
     /* You can change "action-loc-key" to what you want the 'action' button
       to say. (In this case, nothing) */
     "action-loc-key":null},
     "badge":0,
     "sound":"beep.wav"},
"acme1":"bar",
"acme2":42
}
```